# Breadth first search simple improvement

Tags: breadth-first-search

In most resources implementation of BFS is like this(this is [geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-paths-given-source-destination-using-bfs/) implementation):

```
void findpaths(vector<vector<int> >&g, int src,  
                             int dst, int v) 
{ 
// create a queue which stores 
// the paths 
queue<vector<int> > q; 

// path vector to store the current path 
vector<int> path; 
path.push_back(src); 
q.push(path); 
while (!q.empty()) { 
    path = q.front(); 
    q.pop(); 
    int last = path[path.size() - 1]; 

    // if last vertex is the desired destination 
    // then print the path 
    if (last == dst)  
        printpath(path);         

    // traverse to all the nodes connected to  
    // current vertex and push new path to queue 
    for (int i = 0; i < g[last].size(); i++) { 
        if (isNotVisited(g[last][i], path)) { 
            vector<int> newpath(path); 
            newpath.push_back(g[last][i]); 
            q.push(newpath); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

the above implementation suggests that we first add the neighbors to the queue then we will check it that it is our destination or not.

but we can simply check the neighbor is the destination or not when adding the neighbor to the queue (instead of checking it when it is that node's turn) although it is a very minor improvement, it is better than the last one. so why everyone use the previous method for implementing BFS?

Comment: You should post a link to the "geeks for geeks" full implementation so readers could find it more easily in case they wanted more background behind the *horribly*-named variables.

Comment: as you wish. I have posted the link